# add character entity from numerical identifier to input value

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add a couple of character entities to the value for the input.
I can only seem add these character entities when im adding as inline say to the event handler.

Works inline to input

```
value="enter name &#150;&gt;" onfocus="if(this.value=='enter name &#150;&gt;'){this.value=''};
```

Dose not work as i was liking say being called form a function
it displays " &#150;&gt;"

```
if(ds.value==''){
    ds.value='enter name &#150;&gt;';
    }
```

Comment: Maybe changing single quotes to double for second code part might help? I.e. `ds.value="enter name &#150;&gt;";`

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev i have tryed that and didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use unicode:

```
<input value="enter name &#x2D;&#x3E;" onfocus="if(this.value=='enter name &#x2D;&#x3E;'){this.value=''};" onblur="check(this);" />
```

All values are in hex.

```
function check(ds) {
    if(ds.value==''){
        ds.value='enter name \u002D\u003E';
    }
}
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ykadf/).

Comment: yes, very good i replaced \u002D with \u2013, Thanks mate good answer

Answer (score 1):

You can either put direct values in your javascript,
or decode them with simple javascript before assigning.

see : http://jsfiddle.net/mFtVa/1/

```
<input id='inline' value="enter name &#150;&gt;"  />
<input id='func_direct' value=""  />
<input id='func_entity' value=""  />

<script>

    var ds= document.getElementById('func_direct');   

    var de = document.getElementById('func_entity');           


    function decode(str)
    {
         var s = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
         s.innerHTML = str;
         return s.value;
    }

    if(ds.value==''){    
        ds.value='enter name ->';
        }    

    if(de.value==''){   
        de.value = decode('enter name &#150;&gt');
        }
```

Comment: using the textarea's innerHTML's value is one neat hack, thanks! DhruvPathak

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ds.value='enter name \&#150;&gt;';
```